# calculation code to prevent FIFO overflow during data streaming

Tags: performance, c, signal-processing

I am using a dual channels DAQ card with data stream mode. I wrote some code for analysis/calculation and put them to the main code for operation.
However, the FIFO overflow warning sign always occur once its total data reach around 4300 MS (the DAQ on board memory is 8GB).
I am well-known that a complicated calculation might retard the system and cause the overflow but all of the works I wrote are necessary to my experiment which means cannot be replaced (or there is more effective code can let me get the same result). Could anyone point out if there are any ways that I can optimize my code?
My computer has 64GB RAM and Intel Core i7 processor. I always turn off other unnecessary software when running the data stream code.

This is how I process the data:

1. Install the FFTW source code for the Hilbert transform.
2. Allocate buffer size for channel1 and channel2.
3. Use `for` loop to get ch1 and ch2 data from the main buffer.
4. Do the `hilbert` on ch2 and calculate its `absolute` number.
5. Find the max value of ch1 and `abs(hilbert(ch2))`.
6. Calculate `max(abs(hilbert(ch2))) / max(ch1)`.
   Here is the detail of the my calculation code:

```
float SumBufferData(void* pBuffer, uInt32 u32Size, uInt32 u32SampleBits)
{
    // In this routine we sum up all the samples in the buffer. This function 
    // should be replaced with the user's analysys function
    uInt32 i,n;
    uInt8* pu8Buffer = NULL;
    int16* pi16Buffer = NULL;
    int64 i64Sum = 0;
    float max1 = 0.0;
    float max2 = 0.0;
    float min2 = 0.0;
    float Corrected =0.0;
    float AUC = 0.0;
    float* ch1Buffer = NULL;
    double* ch2Buffer = NULL;

    if ( 8 == u32SampleBits )
    {
        pu8Buffer = (uInt8 *)pBuffer;
        for (i = 0; i < u32Size; i++)
        {
            i64Sum += pu8Buffer[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pi16Buffer = (int16 *)pBuffer;
        
        
        
        fftw_complex(hilbertedch2[N]);

        ch1Buffer       = (float*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof(float));
        ch2Buffer       = (double*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof(double));

        // Divide ch1 and ch2 data from pi16Buffer
        for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++)
        {
            ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i*2];
            ch2Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2 + 1];
        }

        // Here hilbert on the whole ch2
        hilbert(ch2Buffer, hilbertedch2);

        
        //Find max value in each segs of ch1 and hilbertedch2
        for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++)
        {
            if (ch1Buffer[i] > max1)
                max1 = ch1Buffer[i];

            if (abs(hilbertedch2[i][IMAG])> max2)
                max2 = abs(hilbertedch2[i][IMAG]);
            
        }
        
        Corrected = max2 / max1; // Calculate the signal correction

        if (Corrected > 0.1)  // check the threshold and calculate area under curve
            AUC += Corrected;
        else
            AUC = 0;
        
        

        
        
    }
    free(ch1Buffer);
    free(ch2Buffer);
    return AUC;
}
```

And the source code from FFTW:

```
void hilbert(const double* in, fftw_complex* out)
{
    // copy the data to the complex array
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] = in[i];
        out[i][IMAG] = 0;
    }
    // creat a DFT plan and execute it
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    // destroy a plan to prevent memory leak
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    int hN = N >> 1; // half of the length (N/2)
    int numRem = hN; // the number of remaining elements
    // multiply the appropriate value by 2
    //(those should multiplied by 1 are left intact because they wouldn't change)
    for (int i = 1; i < hN; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] *= 2;
        out[i][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // if the length is even, the number of the remaining elements decrease by 1
    if (N % 2 == 0)
        numRem--;
    else if (N > 1) {
        out[hN][REAL] *= 2;
        out[hN][IMAG] *= 2;
    }
    // set the remaining value to 0
    // (multiplying by 0 gives 0, so we don't care about the multiplicands)
    memset(&out[hN + 1][REAL], 0, numRem * sizeof(fftw_complex));
    // creat a IDFT plan and execute it
    plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(plan);
    // do some cleaning
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
    fftw_cleanup();
    // scale the IDFT output
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        out[i][REAL] /= N;
        out[i][IMAG] /= N;
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `hilbertedch2`?

Comment: Hi, it is an array with double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Don't allocate memory while processing the data

Reserve space for `ch1Buffer` and `ch2Buffer` once while your program initializes, so that there is enough to handle any value of `u32Size` that you might pass to the function (since you are streaming data, I am guessing that this will be a constant anyway, and there's also the fact that the function `hilbert()` doesn't take a size parameter but uses `N` instead).

## Calculate a plan once and reuse it

Similar to the memory allocation, you should create all the `fftw_plan`s you need once, and then reuse them. You can then also use `FFTW_MEASURE` to create more optimal plans. If you also need your program to start up fast, consider also using [FFTW's wisdom mechanism](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Wisdom.html).

## `double` or `float`?

As chux also mentioned, you are mixing `float` and `double` variables. Do you need both types? If `float` gives you enough precision for what you want to do, use the `float` variants of the FFTW functions to get a large speed boost.

## Compile with `-Ofast -march=native`

Use the compiler flags `-Ofast -march=native` (or whatever the equivalent is for your compiler). This allows the compiler to vectorize your code using SSE instructions: `-march=native` tells it to use the best vector instructions that your CPU supports, and `-Ofast` tells it to cut a few corners when it comes to strict compliance to the standard, but typically it allows it to ignore things like denormal floating point numbers and other very unlikely things that might need extra instructions to handle, or that would even prevent vectorization. With these flags, GCC, Clang and ICC will all vectorize the loop that calculates the maximum absolute values.

Note that using `fabs()` (or `fabsf()` when using `float`s) is very important to keep the code efficient. Chux already mentioned that in his answer.

## Try splitting the maximum calculation loop in two

You have one loop that scans through two arrays simultaneously. That may or may not be less efficient than splitting this into two loops, one for each array. It is hard to predict which will be more efficient, this depends on how fast the CPU can crunch numbers vs. how much memory bandwidth it can sustain, how good the prefetcher of the CPU is, and how the compilers actually compile the loops. So you need to try out both variants yourself and measure the difference in performance.

## Avoid scaling the result of the inverse DFT

Instead of dividing all elements of the array `out` before returning from `hilbert()`, don't scale the output, but instead just divide `max2` by `N` after calculating the maximum.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. In first and the second parts, do you mean I have to set memory allocation and fftw_plan (does the create of IDFT also?)out of the “void”?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "out of the void". The memory allocations and calls to `fftw_plan()` should be done outside the functions that are called to process the stream, so outside `SumBufferData()` and `hilbert()`.

Comment: Got your point and it is what I mean, thanks!

Comment: I am not really get the last part. Could you specify with code or else, thanks!

Comment: I tried to move `fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);` outside to the `hilbert()` but buggy, such as `plan` and `out` need to redefine. Could you point out how to modify once the `fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, out, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);` is outside the void?

Comment: What do you mean `Compile with -Ofast -march=native`, could you give me a more specific example to show how to compile? Because the compiler what I am using is just VS2019. I am just a beginner in C or C++.

Comment: Should I use GCC instead of VS2019?

Comment: Ah, if you use VS2019 then at least use [`/O2`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o-options-optimize-code?view=msvc-160). I don't know which other flags would help with vectorization, maybe someone else can answer that.

Comment: Hi, here are some of my thought after following your guide: 1.Put the memory allocation out of the function didn't make it faster. 2. But move out and reuse the `plan` did upgrade the speed. 3. Splitting to two `for` loops didn't show any difference 4. Scaling the IDFT just divide `max2` by `N` also didn't show difference too.
But, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Could anyone point out if there are any ways that I can optimize my code?

In general, there are no better-than-linear improvements here.

`*alloc()` can be expensive.  Since code is calling it twice and then freeing the pointers at the same time, save one expensive `*alloc()` by doing 1 rather than 2.

With VLA support, it is easy

```
struct {
  float ch1Buffer[u32Size];
  double ch2Buffer[u32Size];
} *x;

x = calloc(1, sizeof *x);
```

... or allocate as an array of `struct`.

```
struct {
  float ch1Buffer;
  double ch2Buffer;
} *x;
x = calloc(u32Size, sizeof *x);
```

`ch1Buffer{]` is not even needed here.  Code does not use the array in an array fashion.

---

**Strange Code**

Why `+=` instead of `=`?  Assignment just as well here.

```
        // AUC += Corrected;
        AUC = Corrected;
```

---

**Integer function used for FP code**

OP commented that `hilbertedch2` is an array with `double`

`abs()` is for integers.

```
// if (abs(hilbertedch2[i][IMAG])> max2)
//  max2 = abs(hilbertedch2[i][IMAG]);
if (fabs(hilbertedch2[i][IMAG])> max2)
  max2 = fabs(hilbertedch2[i][IMAG]);
```

---

I'd expect using `double` for `max2`.

```
// float max2 = 0.0;
double max2 = 0.0;
```

---

If `float Corrected` remains `float`, use `float` constants.

```
// if (Corrected > 0.1) 
if (Corrected > 0.1f)
```

Tip: enable all compiler warnings.

---

**Improve review and maintainability**

Cast not needed.  Size of the referenced object, rather than trying to match the type.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// ch1Buffer       = (float*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof(float));
ch1Buffer = calloc(u32Size, sizeof *ch1Buffer);
```

Comment: Thanks. In the allocation part, the x need to be declared to which kind of variable first? In the AUC part: += means calculate area under curve by summing the data points.

Comment: Yes.  `some_type *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * n);` works fine.

Comment: @Kevin `AUC += Corrected` is only used, at most, once.  It is not in a loop.  It does not sum points

Comment: Then which is better to present to sum the data points?

Comment: @Kevin You need a loop to sum the data points. `for, while, do, ...`

Comment: Hi I tried two parts of your answer, one is the allocation and the other is the fabs.
1. If I used fabs, the value of the data will become `Inf`, that is weird...
2. I used `struct {
  float ch1Buffer;
  double ch2Buffer;...` but in the `     for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++)
        {
            ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i*2];
            ch2Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2 + 1];
        }` the ` ch2Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2 + 1]` showed `Unhandled exception at 0x00000001400036E6 in ... 0xC0000005: Acess violation reading location 0x00000000000000`

Comment: I set my segment size is 7840. As I am using two channels, it will be filled in as ch1ch2ch1ch2ch1ch2.... So, the total `u32Size` is 7840*2=15680. This is how my data stream works to fill up the memory.

Comment: @Kevin Do you have all your compiler warnings enabled? Did you include `<math.h>`?

Comment: Yes, I have already include `<math.h>` but what did you mean enable all the compiler warning? Because I'm quite new in writing C code...

Comment: @Kevin Compilers allow various options.  Some options control the the amount of warnings that are reported.  Unfortunately the default warning set is often minimal.   Research your compiler , save time and enable all warnings.

Comment: Thanks, how about the memory allocation part? I got an error after I put the `struct{}` as you pointed out. However, the error happened in `for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++) {ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i*2]; ch2Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2 + 1];}`
Unhandled exception at 0x00000001400036F1 in GageStream2AnalysisSimple.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

Comment: I suspect allocation error.  Pseudo code suggestion `ptr  = calloc(u32Size, sizeof *ptr);` idiom.  Note no coding of the type here.  Then check the return value: `if (ptr == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemory();`

Comment: I wrote it in the `SumBufferData` and got `unresolved external symbolHandle_OutOfMemory();`

Comment: @Kevin `Handle_OutOfMemory()` is meant to be code you write. What do you want to happen is the allocation failed?

Comment: I've confirmed that the allocation is succeed. It is working fine when I am using `ptr  = calloc(u32Size, sizeof *ptr);` to allocate, but not the `struct{}`. Some people suspect that is because I'm getting the data via unusual way `ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i*2]; ch2Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2 + 1];` However, I have to do that to obey the rule when my data filling to the DAQ buffer ch1ch2ch1ch2ch1ch2.... Otherwise, any better methods?

Comment: 1. I got a fix from my problem now. It should change the format to like `x[i].ch1Buffer += pi16Buffer[i * 2];` However, once it changed to this, it became `Access violation...` error when I tried to use `hilber()`. It is because it no longer a contiguous array? Any thought?
2. The `fabs` is workable now.